# Parsing string sections

Tags: python

What techniques/modules would you use to parse specific string sections. Given lines of the type:

```
field 1: dog        field 2: first        comment: outstanding
field 1: cat        field 2:              comment: some comment about the cat
```

The field names always end with a colon, the field values can be blank and the fields are separated by spaces only. I just want access to the field values. I know how I would do this using regular expression but I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this with Python.

Comment: Is this tab delimited?

Comment: @jamylak no, just spaces.

Comment: looks like regex may be the way to go here, how do you know when there is another field? Is there always more than one space to indicate that?

Comment: By the fields names, actually the format is fixed width.. that is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a fixed width format to me.

If so, you could do this:

```
data={}
ss=((0,19),(20,41),(42,80))
with open('/tmp/p.txt','r') as f:
    for n,line in enumerate(f):
        fields={}
        for i,j in ss:
            field=line[i:j]
            t=field.split(':')
            fields[t[0].strip()]=t[1].strip()
        data[n]=fields    

print data
```

Prints:

```
{0: {'comment': 'outstanding', 'field 2': 'first', 'field 1': 'dog'}, 1: {'comment': 'some comment about the cat', 'field 2': '', 'field 1': 'cat'}}
```

If you want a list:

```
data=[]
ss=((0,19),(20,41),(42,80))
with open('/tmp/p.txt','r') as f:
    for n,line in enumerate(f):
        fields={}
        for i,j in ss:
            field=line[i:j]
            t=field.split(':')
            fields[t[0].strip()]=t[1].strip()
        data.append(fields)
```

In either case, then you can access:

```
>>> data[0]['comment']
'outstanding'
```

Comment: I think a `list` would be more appropriate here, because using `0`,`1` as keys doesn't improves anything. Accessing an item by index is an `O(1)` operation in lists too and they maintain the order as well.

Comment: Easy change if that is important. I don't think that is the main point of the question tho.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
>>> with open("abc") as f:
    lis = []
    for line in f:
        lis.append(dict( map(str.strip, x.split(":")) for x in line.split(" "*8)))
...         
>>> lis
[{'comment': 'outstanding', 'field 2': 'first', 'field 1': 'dog'},
 {'comment': 'some comment about the cat', 'field 2': '', 'field 1': 'cat'}
]

>>> lis[0]['comment']    #access 'comment' field on line 1
'outstanding' 
>>> lis[1]['field 2']    # access 'field 2' on line 2
''
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `csv` module.

Assuming there is a tab delimiter between fields:

```
import StringIO
import csv

input_data = StringIO.StringIO("""field 1: dog  field 2: first  comment: outstanding
field 1: cat    field 2:    comment: some comment about the cat""")

data = []
for row in csv.reader(input_data, delimiter="\t"):
    line = {}
    for item in row:
        value = item.split(":")
        line[value[0]] = value[1].strip()

    data.append(line)

print data
```

prints

```
[{'comment': 'outstanding', 'field 2': 'first', 'field 1': 'dog'}, {'comment': 'some comment about the cat', 'field 2': '', 'field 1': 'cat'}]
```